# Google games services Api - Access Not Configured

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services, google-play-games

I try to access to the Google services API to reset some score into a leader board.

I firstly tried this tool https://github.com/playgameservices/management-tools/tree/master/tools/reset-o-matic, following the step recommended in the project but there was some js error using both Firefox and Chrome.

Then I tried from the developer console calling the Google Play Game Management. But I'm getting a Access not configured exception which is weird because the API is published, the game services is activated and I use the same account I used to authenticate in Google play developer console.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5jlsy5bya1ql7v1/gameservicemanagement.jpg

Any ideas ?

Comment: Hi. Where I can find the google play game management? I can't find it.